# In eclipse How to access identifiers used in C program using AST

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree

How to access identifiers used in C program using AST.

I am new to eclipse plugin development and trying to customize eclipse plug-in to ensure that the variable name, function name, structure or whatever the programmer declares should not contain some specific set of words.

Please let me know some good CDT AST guide with examples. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Over two weeks with zero responses.  Looks like you are not going to get an answer.

I don't know how to help with CDT.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semnanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with is [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html) parses C, builds ASTs and full C symbol table for a variety of dialects of C.   Given this, it is rather easy to enumerate the C symbol table entries, and run an arbitrary predicate on names to see if they violate your conventions.